# Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"

Tags: python, python-3.x

After drop video in bot chat I'm getting this problem: Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"

```
import ffmpeg
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Token", parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'photo', 'audio', 'video', 'voice'])
def addfile(message):
    file_name = 'videoname.mp4'
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    (ffmpeg.input('videoname.mp4')
    .filter('hflip')
    .filter('contrast', contrast=0.9)
    .filter('gamma_b', gamma_b=1.3)
    .filter('saturation', saturation=1)
    .output('out.mp4'))
    bot.send_document(MyID, 'out.mp4' ) #MyID - My Telegram ID
    
        

bot.infinity_polling()
```